# Why I can't execute SQL script from DB Navigator into Intellij IDEA

Tags: postgresql, intellij-idea

Console outputs this:
could not find a "psql " to execute
could not find a "psql " to execute
psql : fatal: could not find own program executable
[IntellijIDEA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXAUQ.jpg)

My enviroment variables:

[image: My enviroment variables]

Comment: Did you restart IntelliJ after adding the env variable? (Including Jetbrains toolbox if you use it). Env variables don't get updated automatically (safest bet is to relog in windows). Also verify that there's a `psql.exe` in your `bin` directory you set in the path

Comment: psql works from command line, also it works when I run a single statement in IDEA. It seems to problem not in variable.

Comment: there seems to be an extra space in the "psql " executable. Maybe recheck the connection configuration or other configuration related to psql